# How to switch back to Rails 5 once the version has been changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't believe I could not figure this out and I have been spending needlessly too long. I used to use rails v. `5.0.0.1.` Somehow when I was cloning apps from railscasts, I switched my rails to `3.1.0.` Ever since then everytime I do `rails new myApp` it created rails v. `3.1.0.`.

I have a project folder name `Project` where I store all my rails app. When I typed `rails -v` in that `Project` folder, I get

```
Projects iggy$ rails -v
Rails 3.1.0
```

I just created new app named `demo` (`rails new demo`), and it generated a new app with rails `3.1.0`.

When I do gem list, this is what I got:

```
demo iggy$ gem list --local rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

autoprefixer-rails (6.5.3, 6.4.1, 6.4.0.2, 6.3.7, 6.3.6, 6.3.1)
coffee-rails (4.2.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 3.1.1)
factory_girl_rails (4.7.0, 4.6.0, 4.5.0)
haml-rails (0.9.0)
jquery-rails (4.2.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.4, 3.1.4)
less-rails (2.7.1)
pry-rails (0.3.4)
rails (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.7.1, 4.2.5, 4.2.4, 4.2.3, 3.1.0)
```

I have tried going to my app that uses rails 5, ran `bundle update` / `bundle install`, but whenever I go to `Project` folder, it always defaults back to rails `3.1.0`. I use `rvm`.

How can I switch back to rails `5.0.0.1` so whenever I create new app it will use latest rails? Moreover in general, is it possible to seamlessly switch between different version of rails app? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uninstall Rails, and re-install it, and reinstalling it will convert the version to the latest.

```
gem uninstall rails
gem install rails # To re-install it.
```

**Edit:**

If you do not want to uninstall Rails, you may need to create a new Gemset for using using Rails 5 throughout your project space. Here's how:

```
rvm gemset create rails-5.0.0
rvm use 2.2.2@rails-5.0.0 --default
```

Kindly replace 2.2.2 with the Ruby version that you would like to use, but it should be later than 2.2.2.

Comment: is there another way to switch rails version without uninstalling it? What if I, say, running rails `5.0.0.0`, and I am cloning an older app that requires older rails version, how can I run, say, rails `3.1.0` when my default rails v is the latest one?

Comment: The new app you created: `demo`, go to its Gemfile, and replace with the line that installs Rails with `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'`. And then do `bundle install`

Comment: I tried it, but it is now complaining (probably because it was installed under older rails v) - in the end of error it says: `Running bundle update will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.`. When I ran `bundle update`, it complained `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":`.

To save me from headache, I went to another app that runs on rails 5, bundle update it, but when I go to `Project` folder it still says that I am still on rails `3.1.0`. How can I make the rails version on Project folder v. 5?

Comment: Are you using rvm?

Comment: I have rvm, but I don't know how to switch rails v.

Comment: The thing is that your global gemset space has been polluted with Rails 3.1, and you need to amend that. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Ah, it works! Thank you so much!! This solved the issue. If you don't mind me asking one more follow-up question, how would you describe a gemset?

Comment: As its name suggests, it is a tool that helps you maintain different set of gems. You can have Rails 5 gem for one project, and for other project Rails 3 gem, and you can easily switch between these two.